# How to know which command-line process is executing?

Tags: java, windows, command-line, process-explorer

How to know that process is running which command using any command-line tool, I am aware that with the help of process explorer we can see it, but is there any command line tool(standalone) or java method I can use to extract this information?

There is a tool called [PsList](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pslist) which gives basic information about process, but there is no option to see command-line

Comment: Task Manager.  Go to View->Select Columns.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I want a command line option to do this through Java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way which is without dependency on other tool or process explorer, using Windows WMI service, run the following command from command prompt :

```
WMIC path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline
```

It just solve my problem.